Reload Data from database in shiny app by clicking action button multiple times
I want to display data from a sql database in a shiny app.
There is always new data coming, so it is convenient to click on the action button to display the newest data.
here is an example of how I do it right now:
library(shiny)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("load_data", "Click button to load recent data"),
  tableOutput("data_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Load data from database
  data_from_db <- reactivePoll(1000, 
                           session = session,
                           checkFunc = function(){
                             if(isTruthy(input$load_data))
                               1
                             else
                               0
                           },
                           valueFunc = function(){
                             dbGetQuery(con, query)
                           }
  )
  
  output$data_table <- renderTable(data_from_db())
}

However, if the actionbutton is clicked once, the if condition is true, and an other click won't lead to a refresh of the data. How is it possible to implement that if the button is clicked a second time to trigger the fresh load from the database?
Searching through stackoverflow, it seems only possible by installing the package shinyjs, or by using JS (action button in table does not respond if i click twice in a row on the same one), but I cannot believe that there isn't another way using shiny and dplyr.

Try using bindEvent(input$load_data) to make your reactive expression run upon changes in your input. Or, if you want the data to be reloaded both periodically by reactivePoll and manually by clicking the button, you might have to write the data into a reactive value

I don't understand the problem exactly. It is not true that the button can be clicked only once, which can be seen if the 1 above is replaced by a print statement and then having a look at the console after clicking the button some times.

@BastiánOleaHerrera The data is already in a reactive value, isn't it? I would like this to be reloaded periodically and after a manual click - here in my question I also agree if the data is only reloaded each time the button is clicked.

@Jan Sorry, I formulated that in a misleading way. The problem is that I use “isTruthy” in the if condition, which does not change after the first click. I thought about reseting the value of the actionbutton to its default right after clicking, but I don't know how to do it. Do you have an idea, of how could I implement this?

As already suggested by @BastiánOleaHerrera I'd use bindEvent or eventReactive:
library(shiny)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("load_data", "Click button to load recent data"),
  tableOutput("data_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Load data from database
  data_from_db <- reactive({
    dbGetQuery(con, query)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$load_data, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$data_table <- renderTable(data_from_db())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Didn't know I had to use the bindEvent outside the ({}). It worked like that. Thanks!
